# Java code with keeping a read in file while loop running with user input

Tags: java, file-io, while-loop

So i'm kinda new with java and I need some help with programing something.
I'm building a program that allows a user to input a color (string) and the run a while loop to look for that color in a file. If the color exists in the file then the user would get points. In the text file I added stringers with integers so the strings are the colors and the integers next to them are the points they are worth.

Text File Ex:
pink:PINK:30
yellow:Yellow:20

Here's the code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainGame {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{

Scanner filechecker = new Scanner(new File("FILE_NAME"));

        int val=0;
        int gamePoints=0;
        int noStrikes=3;
        int strikes=0;

        Scanner Color1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter A color");
        String ColorTaken = Color1.next();

        while (noStrikes>strikes){//added this while loop to keep the loop going if I take this out the program works perfectly but for only for one color search


        while (filechecker.hasNextLine())//checks if color exists in file
        {
        String line =filechecker.nextLine();
        String[] details = line.split(":");//checks for the integer next to the color
        if (line.indexOf(ColorTaken)!=-1)
        {   
            int points = Integer.parseInt(details[2]);// converts the string to int
            System.out.println(""+ColorTaken+" Exists! You Got "+details[2]+" Points ");
            val = 1;//makes statement true
            gamePoints=points;// still working on this not sure how it will work later on but its for the points earned
            noStrikes=3;
        }

        if (noStrikes==3){ //Part of the add-on
             Scanner Color2 = new Scanner(System.in);
             System.out.println("Enter A color");
             String ColorTaken2 = Color2.next();

             while (filechecker.hasNextLine())//checks if color exists in file
             {
             String line2 =filechecker.nextLine();
             String[] details2 = line2.split(":");//checks for the integer next to the color
             if (line2.indexOf(ColorTaken2)!=-1)
             {   
                int points = Integer.parseInt(details2[2]);// converts the string to int
                System.out.println(""+ColorTaken2+" Exists! You Got "+details2[2]+" Points ");
                val = 1;//makes statement true
                 gamePoints=points;// still working on this not sure how it will work later on but its for the points earned

             }
             }
        }




        else
        {
            val = 0; //makes statement false
            continue;

        }
    if(val == 0)
    {

        System.out.println("You Have a Strike! Next Person Must Answer");
        strikes++;
    }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what does or does not work with your code?  You are much more likely to get help if you ask a specific question.

Comment: I want the loop to continue asking the user for color inputs and receiving points for it. The code that I have now does not do that. The first loop works great but the second does not. I want to keep the loop running unless the user inputs a color that does not exist in the file. I also got that working on the first loop but not on the second. The code runs and all but it doesn't say how many points the user gets or if the color exists in the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

try to organize your code a little bit better...

```
while(/*condition for running the game = true*/){
    Color color = askForInput();
    boolean fileHasColor = checkTheFile(color);
    //do something based on the true/false value
}
```

then create method for input...

```
private Color askForInput(){
    //code for getting an input from the player
    Color colorToReturn = new Color(/*based on player input*/);
    return colorToReturn;
}
```

and finally check the file for that color...

```
private boolean checkTheFile(Color color){
    //code to search the file for color
    while(filechecker.hasNextLine()){
        //compare the colors
        if(/*colors match*/) return true;
    }
return false; //this line is reached if no colors match
}
```

this way you separate code into functional parts and it's a lot easier to see what's going on...

Comment: Thank you so much I think I get an idea. i'll definitely try to organize it like you say

Comment: No problem :) if you found this helpful, you could accept as answer or give a vote... Cheers